# Radio data transfer too slow

Tags: communication, high-speed

I need to send data from a camera recorder to a pc. The camera is about 1024/1000 pixels with 15 fps. Now the transmission distance should be at least 100 meters so I'm trying to use radio, but i found transmitters that can only send data with about 2Mbps([this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/AX5031-1-TA05/AX5031-1-TA05OSCT-ND/5803464)). Do you think I can keep the camera feed live (without interruptions or delay)? Also regarding the link above. I think that part should be connected to a socket. Does it come with a socket? Or I need to order it too? (I worked only with parts that are connected directly to the board)

To clarify the situation: the sender is a device that has a camera and a radio transmitter, the video is going to be transmitted directly to a second device (a receiver) that will further process the raw image. I would use wifi but I need a very high range (1km,also wifi is not so effective if there are a lot of obstacles).The video must be received by the second device live (by live i mean that the video must be shown with no frame drop, everything must be smooth, I don't know a better way to explain this since english is not my native language) and with delay as low as possible. Are there other high speed, high range ways of communication I can use?

Comment: We need a better indication of the data rate. Is the picture colour or black and white (monochrome)? Is the image data compressed in any way? Do you have 'line of sight' between the transmitter and receiver (i.e. you can see the receiver from the transmitter, maybe with the help of some poles or masts)?

Comment: The picture is colour. The image is not compressed (as said it is raw image) And the line of sight depends as the sender is a drone.

Comment: What is the data transfer rate? How much power can you use? How often and how long are you going to be using it for? What legislation in your country provides for this power, data rate and usage factor. You need to research this.

Comment: You might be surprised at the range you can achieve with WiFi if you use directional antennas. This may or may not be strictly legal though depending on where you operate this system.

Comment: I know the fact about wifi antennas. But the problem is that i need omnidirectional signal because the sender is a drone

Comment: The law is not the problem

Comment: You pretty much have to compress it if you want to send it as digital video. There are all sorts of cameras which have MPEG2 or MPEG4 compressor ASICs attached.

Comment: What camera are you using by the way? Although communicating video via the transmitter you linked to is technically possible, it will be very difficult to accomplish if you do not have a background in electronics, wireless communications and networks. You might think about moving to solution that would enable you to avoid doing a lot of the low level stuff yourself.

Comment: I'm using a video sensor, not a camera. I have to do everything myself.

Comment: You better enlist some help then unless you aim to be doing this for the next 3 or 4 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work on video conferencing equipment. It is possible to pass video and audio through low bandwidth channels but to do so requires data compression to be applied. There are standardized protocols already defined to do this so it is not necessary to invent new things.

For 15 frames per second video look at the [H.324 protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.324). That can work in a data channel with a bandwidth of 33.6K bits per second. We happened to use one ISDN phone line (64K bits per second) for this protocol.

For 30 frames per second video look at the [H.320 protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.320). That can work in a data channel with a bandwidth of 384K bits per second. The equipment I worked on used three joined ISDN phone lines (384K bits per second) for this protocol.

A radio channel with 2MHz data rate should be able to handle either of these as long as you can support the data compression.

Comment: 15 / 30 fps @ what resolution?

Comment: @m.Alin - look in the ITU specs. Back in the day when I was working in video conferencing we were using NTSC and PAL compatible cameras.